# tkinter making a custom combobox by mixing widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make my custom combobox by packing a button the to right side of an entry widget (after I will use other widgets to make the selector). But whenever a pack the button inside, the entry widgets gets shrunken, it gets the size of the button as it was it's border.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
 
root = Tk()

root.geometry("700x200")

var2 = StringVar()

entry2 = Text(root,width=80, textvariable=var2)
entry2.place(x=170,y=100)


Button3 = Button(entry2, text="▼")
Button3.pack(side="right")
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't put the Button inside the Entry - that will block off some of the area where the user might type.  Put them both inside a Frame, instead.  But if you must do is this way, I think calling `.pack_propagate(False)` on the Entry would at least keep it from shrinking.

Comment: How it won't block some place that user might type if I put both in a frame? can you explain please? @jasonharper

Comment: If you `.pack()` them both in a Frame, they won't be overlapping - the packer doesn't allow that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets by default will shrink or grow to fit their children when using `pack`. That is the defined behavior of `pack`.

When you put the button inside the entry widget, it will end up covering up part of the input area. That would be a usability problem. While you can do that using `pack`, `place`, or `grid` with the correct use of options,  the simplest and most common solution is to put an entry and widget inside a frame.

The best way to do that would be to create a class that inherits from a frame. You can then use an instance of that class as if it were a normal widget. When I do things like this, I'll remove the border from the entry widget and add a border to the frame, so that it looks like the button is inside the entry widget.

```
class CustomCombobox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=2, relief="sunken", highlightthickness=1)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="▼", highlightthickness=0)

        self.button.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

[image: screenshot]